# Can't Connect mySQL database using LAN (C# Winform application)

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, networking

I'm building a winform application with C# lang and MySQL database. There's 3 computer to work with.

1st computer connected with LAN network (Static ip address), it creates hotspot with connect*fy app, and MySQL database server

2nd computer connect to 1st computer with WirelessLAN, connect to its connect*fy app

3rd computer connect to 1st computer with LAN cable (static IP address)

I can only connect 1st and 2nd computer. When I try with 3rd computer it showing message "Unable to connect any specified MySQL host"

Connection Strings that I used

```
        string user = "koas";
        string password = "poipoi";
        string database = "bke_nota_db";
        string host = "10.20.10.129";

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=" + host +
                                        ";database=" + database +
                                        ";username=" + user +
                                        ";password=" + password + 
                                        ";port = 3306" +
                                        ";");
```

Server's IP address that I used is 1st computer static IP adress that connect to LAN.

What should I do?

Comment: try pinging computer 1 from computer 3. It might not be reachable ...

Comment: It's reachable. Computer 1 can ping to computer 3 and vice versa @Übercoder

Comment: are you able to directly query your database in 1st computer from 3rd computer?

Comment: i'm not trying it yet @Martin

Comment: Check the MySql security settings, as it is possible tp restrict access based on ip address. Similarly for firewall settings.